# React Native and Https Agent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, https, axios

Is possible use HTTPS Agent in React Native app?

My code right now is:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import ip from './ip';

import https from 'https';

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false});

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${ip}/api`,
    httpsAgent,
});

export default api;
```

But show the follow Error:

ExceptionsManager.js:76 Error: InternalError Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `https` from file `/mobile/src/services/api.js`, the package `/mobile/node_modules/https/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/mobile/node_modules/https/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /mobile/node_modules/https/index.js(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- /mobile/node_modules/https/index.js/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Comment: The ip.js imported file at line 2, export a const with the IP value how: "https:// IP_AWS"

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: did you found solution? 
same issue me too.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: Any Solution Yet ?

Comment: No specific solution, I've just deployed my API to AWS instance, then hosting with a DNS pointing to instance IP. Then, the Axios on frontend can access the API with HTTPS normally pointing to the API subdomain, without HTTPS Agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Https is a Node Core Module. Have you tried using [rn-nodefy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify)? It makes your React Native application able to use Node Core Modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).